# Error con php al crear un reporta en formato pdf

Tags: php, html

Buenos días estoy usando la librería `fpdf` pero no me da un error  en la conexión 
Este el el error que me genera:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\repor.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\repor.php on line 6

```
<?php
    include 'partials/platilla.php';
    require 'database.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM instituciones";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);


    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);


    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,'Nombre',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,'ID',1,0,'C',1);


    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
       $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['nombre_inst']),1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(20,6,$row['codigo_inst'],1,0,'C');
    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestras esta referenciado al MySQL, ya que indica que no esta retornando informacion la llamada a **query()**, de modo que te recomendaría verificaras que tengas bien configurada la conexion (host, user, pass y puerto).

Fuera de eso, no veo que haya algún error, pero deberías verificar eso y confirmar !

Otra opción es que coloques el código completo para poder tener mayor orientación !

Comment: el error que dice NULL en la función query no va relacionado a que si esta la librería o no, sino que la consulta no esta retornando nada

Comment: @Aprendiz  corregido...